# How can a website know my private IP address?

Tags: ip, router

I recently came across this website called [whatsmyrouterip.com](http://whatsmyrouterip.com/). How does this website know both my private and public router IP address?

Comment: The method is described by and implemented in the code on the page.

Comment: yeah but that only showed me how to get my router ip by myself, I am asking how does the website know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it tries to fetch the web page at each of a list of common router local IPs with JavaScript, deciding that it's found it when one responds. It uses jQuery's `$.get()`, but there are lots of ways to fetch one a web page from within another<sup>1</sup>. This assumes that the router has a web administration panel on port 80, but they usually do.

The relevant code is on and around line 2495 of the source code for the page (view-source:http://whatsmyrouterip.com/):

```
2463   var ips = [["10.0.0.10", []], ["10.0.0.100", []], ["10.0.2.1", []], ...

       <snip>

2495   $.get('http://' + currentIp[0], function () {
2496     foundIp();
2497   });
```

<sup>1</sup>Well, getting the *content* may be tricky because of [Same-Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), but a request that fails because of SOP and one that fails because the site doesn't exist look different so you can still tell if there's something there or not.